# SQL Server Aging Totals Not Matching

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an aging query that ages the amount of items purchased and their costs in 12, 24 and 36 month intervals. The query runs just fine, however my totals don't add up versus a single query used to find the total for one particular supplier.

See below.

```
    SELECT s.SupplierNumber as Supplier_Number 
    , s.suppliername as Supplier_Name
    , i.supplierpartnum as Part_No
    , SUBSTRING(e.account_code,1,5)/*+'-'+RIGHT(e.account_code,7)*/ as Account_Code
    , CASE WHEN e.reference_code = ''
        THEN 'NOREF'
        ELSE reference_code
        END as Reference_Code
    , i.Commodity
    , i.ShortDscrptn as Part_Desc
    , i.unitofmeasure as UOM
    , i.unitprice as Unit_Price
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN COUNT(i.Quantity)
        ELSE 0 END as Annual_Qty_12
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN COUNT(i.Quantity)
        ELSE 0 END as Annual_Qty_24 
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN COUNT(i.Quantity)
        ELSE 0 END as Annual_Qty_36 
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN SUM(i.UnitPrice) 
        ELSE 0 END as  Annual_Spend_12          
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN SUM(i.UnitPrice) 
        ELSE 0 END as  Annual_Spend_24  
, CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN SUM(i.UnitPrice) 
        ELSE 0 END as  Annual_Spend_36  
FROM ekp.dbo.SUPPLIER s   
JOIN ekp.dbo.ORDERHEADER h
    ON s.SupplierID = h.SupplierID
JOIN ekp.dbo.ORDERITEM i
    ON h.OrderID = i.OrderID
JOIN mgnt.dbo.ematch e
    ON h.PONumber = e.po_ctrl_num
    AND i.LineNumber = e.po_sequence_id
WHERE h.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31' 
GROUP BY s.SupplierNumber, s.SupplierName, i.SupplierPartNum,  e.account_code
, i.Commodity, i.UnitOfMeasure, i.UnitPrice, i.ShortDscrptn, h.OrderDate
, e.reference_code
```

I can go ahead and copy the results to a spreadsheet and sum the `Annual_Spend_12` column for a particular `Supplier` and it doesn't match the following:

```
    SELECT SUM(i.unitprice) as Annual_Spend_12 
    FROM ekp.dbo.ORDERITEM i
JOIN ekp.dbo.ORDERHEADER h 
    ON i.OrderID = h.OrderID
JOIN ekp.dbo.Supplier s
    ON h.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
JOIN mgnt.dbo.ematch e
    ON h.PONumber = e.po_ctrl_num
    AND i.LineNumber = e.po_sequence_id
WHERE s.SupplierNumber = '15302'
AND h.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
```

This query just above always totals out much, much higher than the top query. I've also SUMmed and COUNTed the entire aggregate instead and it also doesn't match, actually, it produces the same results as the top query:

```
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.Quantity
        ELSE 0 END) as Annual_Qty_12
, COUNT(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.Quantity
        ELSE 0 END) as Annual_Qty_24 
, COUNT(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.Quantity
        ELSE 0 END) as Annual_Qty_36 
, SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.UnitPrice 
        ELSE 0 END) as  Annual_Spend_12         
, SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2011-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.UnitPrice 
        ELSE 0 END) as  Annual_Spend_24 
, SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderDate >= '2010-01-01'
        AND h.OrderDate <= '2012-12-31'
        THEN i.UnitPrice 
        ELSE 0 END) as  Annual_Spend_36
```

I seriously am dreading writing a stored procedure with temp tables for each aggregate.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  I can see several places that might be throwing it off, but it really depends on the nature of your data...

Comment: You have different depths of aggregation between the queries. Remove everything from the select and group by from the top except for the SupplierNumber and see if that totals.

Comment: Also, you could easily change this to dynamic SQL so you don't have to hard code the dates and would not require annual sproc maintenance.

Comment: Here's the current output: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8cujtjs599gd5o/2013-01-10_120641.png)

Comment: Can you post the results you are getting for the second query?  And then the results for the first query for just that supplier?

Comment: Pinny, do you want the entire results?  We're talking 500k lines.  I can provide a link of the output in say, csv.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding up the results correctly in the first query?  I think you should add an `order by` clause so all records for a given supplier id appear together.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I had attempted an Order By but hadn't attempted to use the SupplierID because it is not in my GROUP BY clause, but then that would be redundant, would it not?  I'm certain the results are correct.  Again, the first query is much LOWER than the query with the specified Supplier.

Comment: @PuroRock . . . I had meant by SupplierNumber -- the variable used in the where.  And, no, `group by` does not (necessarily) order the results.  If you want results in a particular order, you need to use an `order by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... thank you, yes, actually adding the Order By matched the Excel summation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the test is wrong:  you are adding up the values in Excel wrong for the first query.  Here are three valid ways of adding up values in Excel:

- Filter on the values and highlight the column.  Excel will add up the values in the select cells (Excel 2007 and greater).
- Use "sumif()" or "sum({})" to add the totals for a given supplier
- Use a pivot table

The results of a `group by` are *not* necessarily sorted.  They may look sorted, but they still might not be.  One way to do an aggregation is to sort the data and then pick out the results.  However, there are other methods, such as hash aggregation.  And, in a multi-threaded environment, you don't know which thread will return values in what order.